# DB abstraction library like codeigniter

Tags: php, database

Does any one know of a light weight DB abstraction library like the one codeigniter has.
I had a look at Pear:MDB but its not what I am looking for.

I am looking for chaining features. For eg:

```
$this->db->get_where('table_name', 'condition')->row()->'column_name' ;
```

This makes syntax very compact.

TIA,

NB : I am not at all looking for an ORM as might be inferred from the discussion or otherwise.

Comment: @shikhar: I have no answer, but just for curiosity are you trying to avoid writing SQL language queries? That might be not a good idea, you will find on the interent more easly tutorials and support for almost any type SQL queries than for a strange way to query the DB using cahined functions. SQL queries are also more portable and flexible.

Comment: @marco : No I m not avoiding sql queries, its just that sometimes sqls are so obvious that you should abstract them. You can do that with functions, ORM or a middle approach like codeigniter's

Comment: DB abstraction is a myth

Comment: @Gordon: yes ofcourse I do search, and I am not looking for an ORM

Comment: i see no way for function chaining to be more compact than a single function that will accept those arguments directly

Comment: @shikhar Most ORMs I know do have a DAL and a Query Builder, but there is [plenty results for DAL](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=database+abstraction+php) either.

Answer (score 1):

If you need external libraries, then these are very good:

1) http://adodb.sourceforge.net/

2) http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal

3) http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4222-PHP-SQL-database-abstraction-layer.html

4) http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3915-PHP-Database-abstraction-layer-similar-to-PDO.html

Answer (score 0):

[doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) and propel(http://www.propelorm.org/) are my favorites both competing to be leading orms.

personally I'd prefer propel if you do not need doctrine:migrations(particularly if you don't need to version your database)

still keep in mind u'll need versioning one day, so it might be convenient to start with doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

One more to the list:

https://open-mv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/classes/database/

Comment: How many questions you re going to answer today? And how do you think, at which number it will be considered as spam?